# Gradle sourceSets based on gradle.settings

Tags: java, gradle, source-sets

I would like to have some features of my Java library conditionaly built based on custom settings defined in project's settings.gradle.

Example:

**build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: 'java'

sourceCompatibility = 1.7

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

sourceSets {
    extra_feature
}

dependencies {
    compile 'net.java.dev.jna:jna:4.1.0'
}

// I need a way to link the "extra_feature" sourceSets to the default "build" action based on some settings in settings.gradle.
```

**settings.gradle**

```
extraFeatures = true
```

Comment: it is not clear what do you mean by link the "extra_feature".

Comment: This sourceSet includes some Java files (under src/extra_feature/java) and I want to compile these files only if some setting is true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, move your parameter to `gradle.properties`

Second, use simple `if` to control source sets:

```
sourceSets (
   if ("true" == "$extraFeatures") {

   }
)
```

Example (I didnt test it):

```
sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir 'src/java'
            if ("true" == "$extraFeatures") {
                srcDir 'src/java/mysecretcode'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't there a way to evaluate the property directly instead of interpolating it into a string?

Comment: we must convert from string to boolean anyway. may better use `if (Boolean.valueOf("$extraFeatures"))`

Comment: And how can I enable this sourceSet automatically for the "build" task if the settings is set ?

Comment: example added, please try it. but all this build logic seems a bit strange for me

Comment: Thanks for your example, I'll try. Why it seems strange ? If you want to build a library with some optional features (like platform-specific stuff, etc), how would you do ?

Comment: sorry, for library it is ok

Comment: I don't have to use "$extraFeatures" I can directly use "ext.extraFeature" which returns a boolean :-)